# How to get the custom updates in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I try to use `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getupdates` to get updates from telegram with robot, and how can I get custom updates?

Such as, I want to get updates from one telegram group, and in specified time?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to do that.

You have to process all the updates from the API server in Telegram-specified format. The only thing you can provide as a query filter is an `offset` parameter.

---

#### UPD

If the problem is that you always receive the same set of updates, the reason is that you're specifying **incorrect** `offset` parameter for `getUpdates` method.

From the [API docs page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates):

> In order to avoid getting duplicate updates, recalculate offset after each server response

So `offset` **must be different** every time you call `getUpdates`.

How to calculate `offset` for every call:

1. `getUpdates`request returns an array of `Update` [objects](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update).
2. Every `Update` object has a `update_id` property. Iterate over this array, find and store the maximum `update_id` in a variable (`max_upd_id` for example).
3. Use `max_upd_id + 1` as a new `offset` in the next `getUpdates` call.

For the very first call of `getUpdates` use `offset=0`.

Comment: I try to use `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getupdates?offset=1&limit=100`, but it always shows some latest posts, seems to be related to time, is there anything I need to set in robot father?

Comment: just to be clear - the problem is that you always receive the same set of updates, right?

Comment: Yes, I always get the latest content of the updates.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still have the same question. For example, I get some updates `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`, and I call  `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getupdates?offset=0`, I thought I will get `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`, but in fact, I only get `5,6,7,8`, I want to get `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`, can you catch me?